# Match only backticks not inside a <code> block with Regex

Tags: php, regex, parsing

First things first. I know how to parse XML/HTML with simplexml, and I know all the arguments against using RegEx to parse it. This question is for the sake of knowledge.

**What needs to happen**

In a block of text let's say we have the following line of text:

```
The query you need to use is 
<code>SELECT `post_name` FROM table WHERE id= $id</code> 
where `$id` is the `user_ID` we got earlier.
```

How do you match the following:

```
 `$id`
 `user_ID`
```

without also matching

```
`post_name`?
```

**Requirements**

This needs to be a regex-only solution. I understand and know how to use things like `preg_replace_callback` etc to remove `<code>` blocks from the string first, but I'm looking for a regex-only solution. Also, it needs to be able to handle possible attributes like`<code lang="php">`.

The regex needs to **match pairs of backticks that are not between `<code>` and `</code>`** and the matches **may not contain either `<code>` or `</code>`** to handle lone backticks in other contexts.

**The content in the backticks will never be multi-lined.**

**Reasoning**

I'm working on a personal project where this was a possible edge-case. This is not a mark-down type project where it is possible to change the order of the calls. The `<code>` tags are in the source text and not going anywhere.

Also, part of the reason I don't want "use simpleXML" answers is because the backticks are not inside actual `<code>` blocks. It is just a handy way to explain the problem and the solution for `<code>` blocks will work with slight changes.

Comment: "Also, part of the reason I don't want "use simpleXML" answers is because the backticks are not inside actual <code> blocks." - a DOM parser will treat those as text nodes, and you can enumerate through them and do your regexing.

Comment: No DOM parsers of any kind. `<code>` could just as well be plain-text like `happy` and `</code>` could be `sad`.

The only thing you know is what the start and the end "tags" are, and that they are not the same.

Comment: Could there be unmatched, overlapping or nested `<code>` tags, `<code>` tags that are in backticks, comments, strings, or sections that should be ignored, or any other special cases that we should be aware of?

Comment: For the purpose of the question, I'll say it's a magical land where everything is ideal. The only special case it shouldn't match is if a backtick pair contains `<code>` or `</code>` because it means there is an offset problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think regular expressions are a good tool for this, but it can be done if you assume that the code tags aren't nested:

```
`(?:(?!</?code>)[^`])*`(?!(?:(?!<code>).)*</code>)
```

This means:

```
`(?:(?!</?code>)[^`])*`       : Match something in backticks unless it
                                contains <code> or </code> or a backtick...
(?!(?:(?!<code>).)*</code>)   : unless it is followed by a </code>
                                without a <code> first.
```

See the regular expression in action at [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/rjvMGUZ9L9).

Comment: Perfect. The only change I would make is to replace `.` with `[\s\S]` to handle multi-line `<code>` blocks. I know they aren't the best tool, but I was curious to see how it would be done. No worries, it won't be popping up in a project. =)

Comment: Instead of using `[\s\S]` you could simply set the `s` modifier (`PCRE_DOTALL`)